# How to manage event-handler recursion in python turtle?

Tags: python, object, recursion, event-handling, turtle-graphics

I've been working on a Pong game, using the turtle module in Python. Below is my code:

```
from turtle import Turtle, _Screen, TurtleScreen
from random import choice, randrange, randint
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox

class Field(_Screen):
    def __init__(self, width = 1024, height = 600):
        # Get __init__ from _Screen
        super().__init__()
        # Get __init__ from TurtleScreen (parent class of _Screen)
        TurtleScreen.__init__(self, self._canvas)
        if Turtle._screen is None:
            Turtle._screen = self
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.setup(self.width+100,self.height+50)
        self.screensize(self.width,self.height)
        self.title("Pong")
        self.bgcolor("black")
        # Define size of score bar, above the play field
        self.score_height = self.height/10
        # Offset 0 axis line, due to score bar
        self.yzero = -(self.height/2 - (self.height-self.score_height)/2)

class Ball(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, velocity = 5, size = 1, color = "white"):
        super().__init__(shape="circle",visible=False)
        self.color(color)
        self.speed(0)
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(size,size)
        self.setposition(0,field.yzero)
        self.st()
        self.velocity = velocity
        self.dirrection = 0

    def player_collision(self,player):
        bx,by = self.position()
        px,py = player.position()
        x_off = ball.shapesize()[1]*10 + player.shapesize()[0]*10
        y_off = ball.shapesize()[0]*10 + player.shapesize()[1]*10
        if px > 0:
            if (bx > px-x_off and by <= py+y_off and by >= py-y_off):
                return True
        elif px < 0:
            if (bx < px+x_off and by <= py+y_off and by >= py-y_off):
                return True
        return False

    def court_collision(self,court):
        if (ball.ycor() >= ((field.height/2)-
                            court.score_height-self.shapesize()[0]*10)
            or ball.ycor() <= -court.height/2+10): return True
        return False

    def out_left(self,court):
        if self.xcor() <= -court.width/2: return True
        return False

    def out_right(self,court):
        if self.xcor() >= court.width/2: return True
        return False        

class Player(Turtle):
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=0, color="white", up=None, down=None):
        super().__init__(shape="square",visible=False)
        self.color(color)
        self.speed(0)
        self.penup()
        # setup player paddle
        self.shapesize(1,10)
        # Rotate turtle, to allow the use of forward method
        self.setheading(90)
        self.setposition(x,y)
        self.st()
        self.score = 0
        self.height = self.shapesize()[1]*10
        self.velocity = 50
        self.ondrag(self.drag)
        self.upkey = up
        self.downkey = down

    def drag(self,x,y):
        self.ondrag(None) # Disable event handler to avoid recursion
        if y >= (field.height/2-field.score_height) - self.height:
            y = (field.height/2-field.score_height) - self.height
        if y <= -field.height/2+self.height:
            y = -field.height/2+self.height
        self.goto(self.xcor(),y)
        self.ondrag(self.drag) # Reactivate event handler

    def up(self):
        #field.onkeypress(None, self.upkey)
        if (self.ycor()+self.height <=
            (field.height-field.score_height)/2+field.yzero):
            self.forward(self.velocity)
        #field.onkeypress(self.up, self.upkey)

    def down(self):
        #field.onkeypress(None, self.downkey)
        if self.ycor()-self.height >= -field.height/2:
            self.forward(-self.velocity)
        #field.onkeypress(self.down, self.downkey)

class Score(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(visible=False)
        self.speed(0)
        self.color("white")
        self.pensize(3)
        # Draw lower border
        self.penup()
        self.goto(-field.width,-field.height/2)
        self.pendown()
        self.goto(field.width,-field.height/2)
        # Draw upper border
        self.penup()
        self.goto(-field.width,field.height/2-field.score_height)
        self.pendown()
        self.goto(field.width,field.height/2-field.score_height)
        self.penup()
        # Draw score
        self.goto(-100,field.height/2-field.score_height)
        self.write(player2.score,font=("Monospace",50,"bold")) 
        self.goto(100,field.height/2-field.score_height)
        self.write(player1.score,font=("Monospace",50,"bold"))

    def update(self):
        # Clear the previous score
        for i in range(3):
            self.undo()
        # And write the new one
        self.write(player2.score,font=("Monospace",50,"bold")) 
        self.goto(100,field.height/2-field.score_height)
        self.write(player1.score,font=("Monospace",50,"bold"))

class Game:
    def __init__(self,court,difficulty=0):
        # Difficulty = increase in ball speed
        self.difficulty = difficulty
        # Setup event handlers
        court.onkeypress(self.qt, "Escape")
        court.onkeypress(player1.up, player1.upkey)
        court.onkeypress(player1.down, player1.downkey)
        court.onkeypress(player2.up, player2.upkey)
        court.onkeypress(player2.down, player2.downkey)
        court.onkey(self.pause, "p")
        court.listen()
        # Try to implement game pause. Not working, for the moment
        #self.pause = False
        #self.pause_count = 0

    def reset(self):
        ball.setposition(0,field.yzero)
        player1.setposition(player1.xcor(),field.yzero)
        player2.setposition(player2.xcor(),field.yzero)
        ball.dirrection = choice([0,180])   # Left or right
        ball.setheading(ball.dirrection+randrange(-80,80))

    def restart(self):
        self.reset()
        self.player1_score = 0
        self.player2_score = 0
        self.difficulty = 0

    def qt(self):
        prompt = Tk()
        prompt.eval('tk::PlaceWindow %s center' % prompt.winfo_toplevel())
        prompt.withdraw()
        answer = messagebox.askyesno("Quit", "Are you sure you want to quit?")
        if answer == True:
            field.bye()
        return

    # Not currently working
    def pause(self):
        if self.pause_count % 2 == 0:
            self.pause == True
        else:
            self.pause = False

class Play(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(visible=False)
        self.shape("square")
        self.color("white")
        self.speed(0)
        self.penup()
        self.shapesize(2,4)
        self.goto(-field.width/2,field.height/2-field.score_height/2)
        self.write("Play",font=("Monospace",20,"bold"))
        field.onscreenclick(self.click)

    def click(self,x,y):
        print(x,y)
        if (x <= -field.width/2+field.width/2/10 and
            x >= -field.width/2 and
            y >= field.height/2-field.score_height/2 and y <= field.height/2):
            self.color("green")
            self.clear()
            self.write("Play",font=("Monospace",20,"bold"))
            self.color("white")
            self.clear()
            self.write("Play",font=("Monospace",20,"bold"))
            game.reset()
            main()

def main():
    ball.forward(ball.velocity+game.difficulty)
    # Check for paddle collision
    if ball.player_collision(player1) or ball.player_collision(player2):
        ball.setheading(180 - ball.heading())
    # Bounce from upper or lower border
    if ball.court_collision(field):
        ball.setheading(-ball.heading())
    # Check for ball out of field and update player score
    elif ball.out_right(field):
        game.reset()
        player2.score += 1
        score.update()
        game.difficulty += 0.5
    elif ball.out_left(field):
        game.reset()
        player1.score += 1
        score.update()
        game.difficulty += 0.5
    field.ontimer(main)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    field = Field(1280,720)
    ball = Ball()
    player1 = Player(field.width/2,field.yzero,up = "Up", down = "Down")
    player2 = Player(-field.width/2,field.yzero, up = "w", down = "s")
    game = Game(field)
    score = Score()
    play_button = Play()
    #field.mainloop()
```

It kind of works, but if you use the keys to play, it will eventually return an error:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a
>   Python object

It would first seem that the problem is with the `main()` function, but the actual problem is with the event-handler for the key presses. If I only play using the mouse, the game will give no error, it will just feel jerky.

I've read the following subjects so far:

[maximum recursion depth exceeded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53055573/getting-maximum-recursion-depth-exceeded-with-python-turtle-mouse-move)

[Avoid RecursionError in turtle paint code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47686088/avoid-recursionerror-in-turtle-paint-code)

[Turtle.onkeypress not working (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45545469/turtle-onkeypress-not-working-python)

And tried to implement the solutions found there. The only one that works for me is disabling the event-handler for the `ondrag()` function. If I try to use the same solution on the player (uncomment the lines in `up()` and `down()` methods of `Player`) it will only work when `main()` is not running. If I start the main() function it will just run once and deactivate.

So what I need help with is:

1. Avoiding the maximum recursion error. (it only happens when `main()` is active);
2. Making the `ondrag` function work without jerking the `main()` function;
3. the `qt()` method from the `game` class is not properly working if `main()` is running.

So do you guys think I can improve these aspects?

Edit: Below is the full traceback

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Bogey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Bogey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 746, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:/Users/Bogey/Desktop/asd.py", line 209, in main
    ball.forward(ball.velocity+game.difficulty)
  File "C:\Users\Bogey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1637, in forward
    self._go(distance)
  File "C:\Users\Bogey\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\turtle.py", line 1604, in _go
    ende = self._position + self._orient * distance
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: Please show the actual traceback. It will tell us what function is being called recursively.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley I have edited my original post and added the full traceback. But, as I wrote in a comment to cdlane's answer, the issue was from not giving a time argument for ontimer method. The only unresolved issue remains the mouse drag function, wich slows down the ball.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue I see is you're doing too much needless calculation during game play.  For example, consider the `court_collision()` method which gets called on every ball movement:

```
def court_collision(self,court):
        if (ball.ycor() >= ((field.height/2)-
                            court.score_height-self.shapesize()[0]*10)
            or ball.ycor() <= -court.height/2+10): return True
        return False
```

Of all these values, only `ball.ycor()` is changing, the rest should have been computed before game play began and stashed so that the method looks more like:

```
def court_collision(self):
        return not self.wall_top_offset > ball.ycor() > self.wall_bottom_offset
```

Ditto for `player_collision()`, `drag()`, etc.

The `main()` *function* should be really be the `move()` *method* of `Ball`.

I've other nits but they don't have anything to do with game performance.

Comment: You have some good points. Indeed I make some unnecessary calculations and the main could have been implemented as a Ball method. I took your remarks into consideration and changed my code, but found that the issue described in my question was actually from the ontimer() method, which I was using without an argument for time. I suppose the frequency was too high to handle, or something, I don't know. Even 1ms was enough to avoid crashing.